# USB3 to SATA adapter performance?

Tags: sata, usb-storage, usb-3, sata-to-usb, usb-to-sata

Does anyone know how well one of these adapters performs? I want to connect a SATA SSD through a USB3 port but I'm afraid that an adapter will reduce the performance significantly...

Also is there a difference between cheaper and costlier adapters? For example $2 and $20?

Comment: What SSD make and model, exactly? They vary greatly in speed.

Comment: It also matters if you have a USB3 to SATA convertor which supports [USB attached SCSI protol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI).

Comment: I haven't chosen one yet, but I'm looking for something at around 400mb/s at least. It will be a model of 240-520GB, I don't care about any features as long as it's reliable and performs well. Also cheap.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if it's the right place for your question (or for my answer) but I'll share what I've got.

I have two from IOCrest:

USB 3.1 Gen 2 (ASMedia ASM1351): [http://www.amazon.com/IOCrest-Type-C-Controller-Adapter-SI-ADA20175/dp/B010U57FP2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010U57FP2)

USB 3.0 (JMicron JMS567): [http://www.amazon.com/IO-Crest-Adapter-Drives-SI-ADA20155/dp/B00LPUV06C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LPUV06C)

I use both of them on a USB 3.0 port (Intel H87). UASP is supported *by the host and* the adapters. SSD is a Silicon Power S70 240GB (exactly the same one for both, I switch back and forth).

ASMedia ASM1351:

[image]

JMicron JMS567:

[image]

As you can see, the sequetial R/W wouldn't be much of a problem. But the random R/W performance can vary quite a lot. Apparently it is (partly?) because of the maximum number of streams/queues supported by the chip (`queue_depth` seen in Linux under UAS mode are '30' and '14' respectively).

Make sure you at least enable the write cache on the disk, like this:

[image]

Otherwise the performance will be something like this:

[image]

*This is the same case with SATA as well.*

In case this looks too much like an advertisement for IOCrest. I'll tell a bit about the ones from StarTech as well.

I got one USB 3.0 from StarTech. Not quite certain about the its chip. StarTech told that it's a ASMedia ASM1051E, but from what I can see in the system it could actually be an ASM1153 or ASM1153E: [http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-SATA-Drive-Adapter-Cable/dp/B00HJZJI84/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HJZJI84)

I use it on an ancient (but sacredly decent) Intel X25-M 80GB 50nm:

[image]

As you can see, even when it's an older chip from ASMedia, but it still beats JMicron in the random performance. (It's slightly more expensive though, but that's generally true for the ones from StarTech.)

StarTech also provides USB 3.1 Gen 2 ones (Type-A and Type-C). They use the same chip (ASM1351) as the one from IOCrest. Although IOCrest provides its USB 3.1 Gen 2 one with an additional USB 3.0 Type-B to Type-C cable, but I don't think you can get the power supply that can be provided by a native Type-C cable from that. Instead, the ones from StarTech has non-detachable cables. Though I do not own one myself and hence never tested it on a 3.5" HDD or some power hungry SSDs, so I am not certain whether its Type-C one really performs better in terms of power supply.

*Speaking of this, do **NOT** expect that all the SSDs would work with an adapter that is powered by a single USB 3.0 Type-A port.*

Comment: So there is a big difference between cheaper ones and not it seems. I'm considering just buying an external SSD instead, because I would spend a lot on the adapter as well. Cheapest I found was $41 (with shipping), which would be half the price of the SSD.

Comment: It depends to be honest. Maybe some of the cheaper ones available in your local market use the same chips. It's just you probably won't be able to tell until you've got one.

Comment: Just make sure both *your host* and the adapter/external SSD you are going to buy support UASP, otherwise their *random 4K QD32* performances are probably gonna be the same as its *random 4K* ones, which will be low as you can see.

Comment: I wouldn't need an internal SSD if I couldn't get my hands on a low-priced connector in the first place. So i'll just buy an external SSD instead, as otherwise I might be stuck with the SSD and nothing to do with it. Thanks for the insight though.

Comment: The ASM1351 controller supports TRIM / UNMAP with the latest firmware update.

Comment: @Locutus You are referring to the update from StarTech, right? LBPME bit is statically 0 though, which means it (sort of) won't work under Linux, while Windows does not check the bit.

Comment: There's a newer update for the ASM1351 on Station Drivers. I don't know about the LBPME bit.

Comment: @Locutus the update on Station Driver is the same one as / from [SIIG](http://www.siig.com/download/search/?keyword=JU-SA0Q12-S1), which does not have UNMAP->TRIM translation implemented. Why would you even think it does?

Comment: @TomYan But the update from StarTech does have UNMAP? The Station Drivers one looks like a newer version number.

Comment: @Locutus Yes. It appears to me that ASMedia (and JMicron) would release different "branches" of firmwares to the adapter vendors, and firmware with UNMAP->TRIM support (or some other feature) is only provided if the vendor specifically request for it.

Comment: The same firmware 150708_B1_01_03 on StarTech's website for the ASM1351 adapter is listed on Station Drivers for the ASM105x controller.

Comment: @Locutus they are not the same. The actual versions of StarTech's firmware are 150708_B1_0A_01 (original in the adapter without UNMAP support) and 150708_B1_0A_02 (update on StarTech website with UNMAP support). The version can be revealed with the Mass Production Tool available in the SIIG zip archive (as well as the filename of the actual firmware file extracted to user's Temp folder).

Comment: If possible, it'd be nice to see benchmark results from having one of the SSDs plugged directly into the SATA port instead of using the USB adapter, so we can see how much (if any) the USB adapter slows down the performance.

Comment: @pacoverflow I did SATA vs USB benchmark of ASM1351 here - https://imgur.com/a/rcbTt

Comment: One can get relevant information by googling `ASM1351`, `ASMT-2135` and `ASM105X`. Unfortunately I didn't find official firmware repository, but there is this [Russian page](http://www.usbdev.ru/files/asmedia/asmt2135firmware/) that list some. Its not exhaustive, at least they are missing `151030_b1_1b_01` which I got flashed from factory.

Comment: There is nice write up on [ASmedia MPTool](https://davidzou.com/blog/generic-asm1153e-based-m2-usb3-bridge) that can be used to flash new firmware, check the current one and verify UASP support.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík I know right. ASMedia doesn't "officially" release firmware builds to users but only to vendors upon their specific request (such as UNMAP/TRIM support, spin-down timer...). The version numbers are unreliable (as in, larger doesn't necessarily means more updated and better quality), the one comes with the MPTool released by SIIG (http://www.siig.com/download/search/?keyword=JU-SA0Q12-S1 probably the source of the pack your found elsewhere) is for ASM1351 and is decent enough (stable hot swap support, for example), but it lacks UNMAP/TRIM implementation.

Comment: StarTech provides various builds with TRIM support. They are of different quality respectively as well. I found the one for the adapter cables to be the best build (https://sgcdn.startech.com/005329/media/sets/sat3cb_Firmware/Firmware.zip). You can run the updater and it will extract the firmware file usable with MPTool in the user temp AFAIR.

Comment: @TomYan oh great thanks for the link! Also I've received answer from Plugable regarding the TRIM support - [it's being worked on](https://pastebin.com/bp9cwL65).

Comment: @TomYan I have tried the firmware you suggested and it is great! 1) it enabled TRIM/UNMAP support 2) it greatly improved write speed ([benchmark](https://imgur.com/a/PGPQx) available here).

Comment: The poor write performance of JMicron chips has been noted before. This applies to sequential writes too. [See this review](https://www.everythingusb.com/drive-adapters.html) on JMS578 for example. Overall I think the conclusion is to stick with ASMedia. Some benchmarks on the JMS580 and VIA VL716 3.1 Gen 2 bridges would also be nice to compare with these. An important test case other than speed is to check stability over long transfers. It has been widely reported that these Gen 2 chips overheat and drop out on sustained full-speed transfers of over ~400GB.